# Change x-variable bin counts of a histogram

Tags: r, count, histogram

I have plots that are .25 ha and I need my data to be displayed as 1 ha. I'm trying to make the following graph but multiplying the counts by 4 (so I have a full hectare instead of a quarter). However, all posts seem to deal with changing axis titles, values, etc., but I need to change the actual histogram frequency counts.

[Histogram x-variable in size classes plotted by factor variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt0n1.png)

```
ggplot(liveTrees, aes(diam1DBH)) +
geom_histogram(binwidth =10) +
facet_wrap(~site) +
ggtitle("Stems/0.25ha by Size Class") +
ylab("Stems/0.25ha") +
xlab("Diameter Class")

liveTrees = my data 
diam1DBH  = diameter (numeric, continuous) 
site = plot location (factor)
```

Original code:
What I've tried: `

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(liveTrees$site))) { 
    test<-hist(liveTrees[liveTrees$site== unique(liveTrees$site)[i], "diam1DBH"],   plot = F) 
    b <- barchart(test$counts*4, width = 10, xlim=c(0,350), cex.axis = 0.85) 
    axis(side = 1, at = "b", cex.axis = 0.85)
}
```

But I keep getting

> Error in axis(side = 1, at = "b", cex.axis = 0.85) : no locations are
>   finite In addition: Warning message: In axis(side = 1, at = "b",
>   cex.axis = 0.85) : NAs introduced by coercion

So, with this I can get the counts, but the numbers aren't right and they're not in a useful format.

My data is a data.frame, example: [data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znNOY.png)

What I need is the sum of each diameter class, each bin frequency amount, multiplied by 4. I've been trying to do this but can't get it to work, any help is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you multiply the frequencies by 4, the values will change but the graphs will still look the same, so there are two options, one is to simply change the axis value labels, or the other simpler way is to add the data 4 times. For example:

```
ggplot(rbind(data, data,data,data), aes(variable_X)) + geom_histogram(binwidth =10)
```

> This way the data is multiplied, and no new data.frame is made that could confuse analysis later on.